# convert Year and Month data into date format in python

Tags: python, date

I have use the following code to convert the dates into YYYY-MM format. However, there is an error encountered. I am unsure what went wrong.

```py
dateformat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dateformat['year_month'], format='%Y%m')

array(['20071', '20072', '20073', '20074', '20075', '20076', '20077',
       '20078', '20079', '200710', '200711', '200712', '20081', '20082',
       '20083', '20084', '20085', '20086', '20087', '20088', '20089',
       '200810', '200811', '200812', '20091', '20092', '20093', '20094',
       '20095', '20096', '20097', '20098', '20099', '200910', '200911',
       '200912', '20101', '20102', '20103', '20104', '20105', '20106',
       '20107', '20108', '20109', '201010', '201011', '201012', '20111',
       '20112', '20113', '20114', '20115', '20116', '20117', '20118',
       '20119', '201110', '201111', '201112', '20121', '20122', '20123',
       '20124', '20125', '20126', '20127', '20128', '20129', '201210',
       '201211', '201212', '20131', '20132', '20133', '20134', '20135',
       '20136', '20137', '20138', '20139', '201310', '201311', '201312',
       '20141', '20142', '20143', '20144', '20145', '20146', '20147',
       '20148', '20149', '201410', '201411', '201412', '20151', '20152',
       '20153', '20154', '20155', '20156', '20157', '20158', '20159',
       '201510', '201511', '201512', '20161', '20162', '20163', '20164',
       '20165', '20166', '20167', '20168', '20169', '201610', '201611',
       '201612', '20171', '20172', '20173', '20174', '20175', '20176',
       '20177', '20178', '20179', '201710', '201711', '201712', '20181',
       '20182', '20183', '20184', '20185', '20186', '20187', '20188',
       '20189', '201810', '201811', '201812', '20191', '20192', '20193',
       '20194', '20195', '20196', '20197', '20198', '20199', '201910',
       '201911', '201912', '20201', '20202', '20203', '20204', '20205',
       '20206', '20207', '20208', '20209', '202019', '202011', '202012',
       '20211', '20212', '20213', '20214', '20215', '20216', '20217',
       '20218', '20219', '202110', '202111', '202112', '20221', '20222',
       '20223', '20224', '20225', '20226', '20227', '20228'], dtype=object)

ValueError: unconverted data remains: 9
```

Comment: `print(dateformat['year_month'])`?

Answer (score 0):

Resolve the error by including exact=False

dateformat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(dateformat['year_month'], format='%Y%m', exact=False)